# Use a local modified version of a package installed with pip

Tags: python, pip

I have installed a tool through `pip install` in an anaconda environment. I use this tool by calling it through the command window. However, I want to make some changes in some functions of this tool locally and be able to run this instead of the one installed with pip. I am trying to do `cd` to the folder before executing the command, but it still uses the one installed with pip. Is there a way to make it clear that I want to use the modified version?

Comment: My recommendation is to read about conda environments.  The solution to your problem would be to create 2 environments and switch between them. https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: @user1877600 Based on my understanding, even with a second environment this does not solve the problem, since I will also have to install the tool with pip in it.

Comment: Perhaps you could download the source code of the tool/package, modify it, and then use it as a python module? This should be pretty straight-forward for libraries which are pure-python.